# How can I set this value using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was wondering what was the correct way to do this ajax function using javascript. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : '',
    'type' : 'POST',    
    'data' : last_time,     
    'data' : "last_time=yes",
    'beforeSend' : function () {

    },
```

How can I set 2 data values?

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['last_time'])){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `$.ajax` method expects either

- a querystring `last_time=yes`
- or a JSON object `{last_time: "yes"}`

*Not both*. Like so...

**Query string:**

```
var dataString = "last_time=yes&date=4162014&action=last_time";

$.ajax({
    'url' : 'localhost/actions/last_time.php',
    'type' : 'POST',       
    'data' : dataString,
    'beforeSend' : function () {

    },
```

or

**JSON:**

```
var data = {
  action: "last_time",
  last_time: "yes",
  date: "4162014"
};

$.ajax({
    'url' : 'localhost/actions/last_time.php',
    'type' : 'POST',    
    'data' : data,
    'beforeSend' : function () {

    },
```

With a simple php backend

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
  switch ($_POST['action']}) {
    case 'last_value':
      $return_array = array(
        "status"  => "great!",
        "message" => "Hey there!"
      );
      die(json_encode($return_array));
      break;

    default:
      $return_array = array(
        "status"  => "default"
      );
      die(json_encode($return_array));
      break;
  }
} else {
  die("access denied");
}
```

Comment: Yea but how do I post to the desired PHP post??    `if(isset($_POST['last_time'])){`

Comment: you set the url the absolute or relative path of your php script which is accepting the `$.ajax` request. I'll update

Comment: But I have multiple POSTS on that URL

Comment: could you provide some PHP code for further assistance? With php it is conventional to pass an action value through the query string or JSON object `action=last_time` or `action: "last_time"`, and utilize the action value to create a controller which only fires the necessary code back if the action is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could only have one property with name `data` (object keys must be unique, you could think javascript object as a hash map struct).

It should be a query string like `'foo=yes&bar=no'` or an object `{foo: 'yes', bar: 'no'}`.